# Addition of two times in JAVA

Tags: java, date, time, duration, timeofday

I want to make the addition of two times (java.sql.Time) without using any other library (java.date, LocalTime..), I get always the time under 1 hour.

```
java.sql.Time

Time heureDebut="09:00:00";
Time heureFin="00:15:00";
long heureDebuts = heureDebut.getTime()+heureFin.getTime();
Time tt = new Time(heureDebuts);
//I get 08:15:00 as a result
```

Comment: have you checked the time library of java itself?

Comment: Yes, Im using getTime() now but the problem was that the hour is always under 1 hour

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t use `java.sql.Time`. That class is a hack on top of the already poorly deisgned `java.util.Date` class and is long outdated. When in use, it was for at ime of day, never for an amount of time like for example a duration. For a time of day use `LocalTime` and for an amount of time use `Duration`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If my French sufffices (which I believe it does), something starts at 9:00, but it already ended at 0:15 in the night? And then you want to add those two times? If this makes any sense at all, please explain, because to me it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

You said you wanted to use no library class but `java.sql.Time`. Still for you and for everyone else reading this I am suggesting that you *don’t* use the `Time` class. One, the class is long outdated, two, the class is horribly designed, three, it’s the wrong class for your purpose, and four, I am not convinced that it can be used for this at all. You may get the impression from the answer by Amine ABBAOUI that it *is* possible, but that answer is cheating in two ways: It is using methods that have been deprecated for 23 and a half years, which I suggest that no one should want to do either; and it’s doing all of the work *outside* the `Time` class.

java.time is so much nicer to work with. It has been built into Java since Java 8 and has also been backported to Java 6 and 7.

It’s not perfectly clear to me, but I am assuming that `09:00:00` is a start time and `00:15:00` is a duration, and you want to calculate an end time by adding the duration to the start time.

```
    LocalTime heureDebut = LocalTime.of(9, 0);
    Duration heureFin = Duration.ofMinutes(15);
    
    LocalTime resultat = heureDebut.plus(heureFin);
    
    System.out.println(resultat);
```

Output is:

> 09:15

### If you were getting `Time` objects from your database

If you were getting `java.sql.Time` objects from an SQL database that stores both start time and duration as `time` datatype (which is incorrect) and you cannot control the database design: Get `LocalTime` objects from the database. Convert the duration to a `Duration` object and then proceed as I did before. For example:

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "select heure_debut, heure_fin from votre_table where id = 4;");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        LocalTime heureDebut = rs.getObject("heure_debut", LocalTime.class);
        LocalTime heureFin = rs.getObject("heure_fin", LocalTime.class);
        Duration dur = Duration.ofNanos(heureFin.getLong(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY));
        
        LocalTime resultat = heureDebut.plus(dur);
        
        System.out.println(resultat);
    }
```

Since a `LoalTime` opposite a `Time` isn’t connected to any time zone, the conversion above will give you the expected result.

### If you don’t want to use java.time

If you don’t want to use java.time (not that I’d understand), my best suggestion is that you do everything by hand and don’t use any library class at all. It’s no solution that I recommend, it’s no good solution, but it’s not as bad as trying to make the outdated and poorly designed `Time` class behave in a way that it was never designed to.

### What went wrong in your code?

Apart from the fact that you cannot assign a string to a `Time` object, you have got a time zone offset problem. It seems your time zone was at UTC offset +01:00 on January 1, 1970. A `Time` is a `java.util.Date` on January 1, 1970. While not well documented, the time is in the default time zone of the JVM. So your `09:00:00` in your time zone is the same as 08:00:00 UTC. And `00:15:00` is 23:15:00 on the night before (December 31, 1969). The `getTime` method that you use gets the number of milliseconds since 00:00:00 *UTC*. So in the first case you get 8 hours worth of milliseconds, and in the second case you get a negative amount equal to *minus* three quarters of an hour. You added those and got milliseconds enough for 7 hours 15 minutes. You fed those back into a `Time` object and got 07:15:00 UTC, which prints as 08:15:00 in your time zone.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pseudo code as follows:

```
    Time heureDebut= Time.valueOf("01:00:00");
    Time heureFin=Time.valueOf("00:15:00");
    
    int hours = heureDebut.getHours() + heureFin.getHours();
    int minutes = heureDebut.getMinutes() +heureFin.getMinutes();
    int seconds = heureDebut.getSeconds()+heureFin.getSeconds();

    if (seconds >= 60) {
      minutes =minutes+1;
      seconds = seconds % 60;
    }
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      hours =hours+1;
      minutes = minutes % 60;
    }
    
    Time result=new Time(hours,minutes,seconds);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be `Daylight Saving Time` issue.

```java
Time base = Time.valueOf("09:00:00");
Time additional = Time.valueOf("00:15:00");
long additionalTime  = additional.getTime() - additional.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
System.out.println(new Time(base.getTime() + additionalTime));
```